# Store userid in memory IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, asihttprequest

I made an IOS Application with a login function. I use the ASIHTTPRequest for this to check if the user exists in a MySQL database. All works fine but i want to pass the userid trough other viewcontrollers or retrieve it on other parts of the app.

Can someone push me in the right direction how to do this in the best and most secure way?

This is my the way i do a POST HTTP request to a PHP script:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"*SOME_URL*"]];
```

In a callback i can retrieve the users ID, but i want to store this ID in the memory of the app for further use.

Thanks.

Comment: Uh... MySQL doesn't exactly... Work on iOS.  Core Data wraps SQLite.  Also, perhaps you could show us what you have so far so it's not just you demanding code.

Comment: How long do you want to keep the password and login? ASIHTTPRequest allows to save credentials in keychains (set "useKeychainPersistence" to YES ), so they can be retrieved anywhere in your app using static methods (+ (NSURLCredential *)savedCredentialsForHost:(NSString *)host port:(int)port protocol:(NSString *)protocol realm:(NSString *)realm;)

Comment: Thanks for your message, i didnt want to store the username and password, only the response with the UserID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store `userId` in the `AppDelegate`.

---

Declare a `userId` property in `AppDelegate.h` with the following code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userId
```

And then synthesize it in `AppDelegate.m` with the following code:

```
@synthesize userId;
```

---

You can then use `userId` from anywhere in your app. Add an import for the `AppDelegate` in the class you want to use `userId`, as follows:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

To retrieve the `userId` use the following code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *userId = [appDelegate userId];
```

And to set the `userId` use the following code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate setUserId:YouValueRetrievedByInternetOrWhateverYouWant];
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a session class that works as a singleton and can be accessed with a static method.

To do this you can add a static method

```
+ (Session *)sharedInstace {
    static Session *session;
    if (!session)
        session = [Session new]; // there are more proper ways to instantiate a singleton class, not gonna get into it now

    return session.
}
```

On that class .h you should add a NSString (or a class of your choice or whatever you want) and you can access it from wherever with `[Session sharedInstance].userID`

Comment: Hi, that looks like a complicated way, maby more secure than storing in delegate? Thanks for your answer. Got what i needed.

Comment: Storing one variable is not a problem, but in my experience after years of working on the same app, your AppDelegate can start to get crowded and you need to look for other options :) and it's not really complicated, you don't need to do heavy app delegate casting everywhere, and you leave the app delegate to it's real function which is managing application events.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, if you're going to implement singleton pattern, I might suggest `dispatch_once`: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/