# ios/xcode/objective c: set and get session variable

Tags: ios, singleton, session-variables, userid

This should not be that hard but I cannot get it to work.  IOS newb trying to set userid in session instance following the answer by Ismael [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705093/store-userid-in-memory-ios).  But cannot access value of userid in other class.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Session.h
@interface IDSession : NSObject
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *userid;
+ (IDSession *)sharedInstance;  
@end

Session.m
#import "IDSession.h"
@interface IDSession()
@property (readwrite,copy)NSString * userid;

@end

@implementation IDSession

+ (IDSession *)sharedInstance {
    static IDSession *session;
    if (!session){
        session = [[IDSession alloc] init];
        //include this class in other class and reference userid with [IDSession sharedInstance].userid
        NSString * userid = @"1";
    }
    return session;
}
@end
in retrieving class.

#import "session.h"

   NSString *userid =[Session sharedInstance].userid;
    NSLog(@"userid retrieved from session variable is %@",userid);
```

The value that appears in log is (null)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: BTW, when doing singletons, one would generally use dispatch_once, yielding a thread safe singleton. See stackoverflow.com/q/9119042/1271826

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate....But haters will be haters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a local `userid` variable, not the property of the singleton.

Rather than:

```
NSString *userid = @"...";
```

You want:

```
session.userid = @"...";
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I don't exactly understand difference between local variable and property of singleton but I will research that.